# How to dynamically create forms

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi 10.4 application with 20+ forms that are created dynamically.
There is a function that creates the form like:

```
Procedure SetForm(nForm : ShortInt);
Begin
Case nForm of
1: begin
              If not Assigned(Form1) then
                             Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
              Form1.Show;
              End;
2: begin
              If not Assigned(Form2) then
                             Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
              Form2.Show;
              End;
…
End;
```

The question is:
Can I create a generic function to create the forms like :

```
Procedure SetForm(nForm: ShortInt);
Begin
xForm : TForm;
xForm := arrayForm[nForm];    // Array containing all forms;
if not Assigned(xForm) then
              Application.CreateForm((some cast as TComponentClass), xForm);
xForm.Show;
end;
```

To complicate matters some forms have a function that needs to execute before show, something like:

```
xForm.SetUser(nUser);
```

I tried this just to create and activate the form

```
...
type
  TFormInfo = record
    ClassType: TFormClass;
    Form: TForm;
  end;

procedure CreateForm(nForm: ShortInt);

var
  arrayForm: array[1..2] of TFormInfo = (
    (ClassType: TFormParam; Form : nil),
    (ClassType: TFormCliGrid; Form: nil)
  );

implementation

procedure CreateForm(nForm:ShortInt);
var xForm:TForm;
begin
    xForm := arrayForm[nForm].Form;
    if not Assigned(xForm) then
        begin
        xForm := arrayForm[nForm].ClassType.Create(Application);
        arrayForm[nForm].Form := xForm;
        end;
    xForm.Show;
end;
```

When I tried to change the combobox in the second Form (FormCliGrid) on FormActivate

```
...
comboStatus.Items.BeginUpdate;
```

I got the 'Access Violation'

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you are asking for is quite doable, using metaclasses with TForm's virtual constructor.

For example, you can create a base class to access the common functionality for all Forms, eg:

```
type
  TMyBaseForm = class(TForm)
  public
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TMyBaseFormClass = class of TMyBaseForm;
```

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TMyBaseForm)
  public
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere); override;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TMyBaseForm)
  public
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere); override;
  end;

  ...
```

```
type
  TFormInfo = record
    ClassType: TMyBaseFormClass;
    Form: TMyBaseForm;
  end;

var
  arrayForm: array[0..1] of TFormInfo = (
    (ClassType: TForm1; Form: nil),
    (ClassType: TForm2; Form: nil)
  );

Procedure SetForm(nForm: ShortInt);
Var
  xForm : TMyBaseForm;
Begin
  xForm := arrayForm[nForm].Form;
  if not Assigned(xForm) then
  begin
    xForm := arrayForm[nForm].ClassType.Create(Application);
    arrayForm[nForm].Form := xForm;
  end;
  xForm.SetUser(nUser);
  xForm.Show;
end;
```

Alternatively, if using a base class is not an option, you can use an interface instead, eg:

```
type
  ISetUser = interface
    ['{6cc8854b-f945-4a0d-ab13-624a13eaade1}']
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere);
  end;
```

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm, ISetUser)
  public
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere);
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm, ISetUser)
  public
    procedure SetUser(nUser: UserTypeHere);
  end;

  ...
```

```
type
  TFormInfo = record
    ClassType: TFormClass;
    Form: TForm;
  end;

var
  arrayForm: array[0..1] of TFormInfo = (
    (ClassType: TForm1; Form: nil),
    (ClassType: TForm2; Form: nil)
  );

Procedure SetForm(nForm: ShortInt);
Var
  xForm : TForm;
  Intf: ISetUser;
Begin
  xForm := arrayForm[nForm].Form;
  if not Assigned(xForm) then
  begin
    xForm := arrayForm[nForm].ClassType.Create(Application);
    arrayForm[nForm].Form := xForm;
  end;
  if Supports(xForm, ISetUser, Intf) then
    Intf.SetUser(nUser);
  xForm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your answer but it didn't work. I might be doing something wrong.
I tried the second solution but I got an 'Access Violation' trying to access some object inside the form.

Comment: @ZetaSistemas then please update your question to show the code you tried that is not working for you.